# Javascript variable seems to be static

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to develop a website written in PHP which includes a page that users use it to register on website.
In selecting country section of this page, I'm trying to use LOOPJ (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html) jQuery Autocomplete script.
When I try to search and make a suggestion list, I want to send another field's data which is located in a textbox in the form. So I tried to use the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var countryfrom = $("input#country2").val();
        $("#city-input-custom-limits").tokenInput("autocomplete/city_search.php?country=" + countryfrom, {
            searchDelay: 1000,
            minChars: 3,
            tokenLimit: 1
        });
    });
```

Everything is working fine. But when I change "country2" text box value, the value of the `countryfrom` does not change and initial value of the `country2` returns to `city_search.php` page.

Could anyone make suggestions why `countryfrom` value does not change while `country2` is changed?

Comment: you are reading hte input value only once

Comment: @ArunPJohny everytime new search is performed, this funcrion is called again. So `countryfrom` must be updated.

Comment: @ImanHejazi no, it doesn't

Comment: Maybe I should look deeper, I'm trying to figure it out hole of the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should listen to `keyup` event:

```
// Cache the element
var $elem = $("#city-input-custom-limits");

$("#country2").on('keyup', function() {
     var country = $.trim(this.value);
     $elem.tokenInput("autocomplete/city_search.php?country=" + country, {
         searchDelay: 1000,
         minChars: 3,
         tokenLimit: 1
     });
}).triggerHandler('keyup'); // execute the handler on DOM ready
```

Comment: @undefined @dianuj Thanks for giving me the clue. Because `country2` is comboBox, I changed `keyup` to `change`. But Every time I select another option in `country2`, another `city-input-custom-limits` filed will be created in the page.

Comment: @ImanHejazi You are welcome, can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net? By the way, my family name is Hejazi too.

Comment: @undefined As I see in your profile, You are from persia, I'm from there too, and this is my pleasure. I fixed it by your help and I marked my question as 'solved'. Regards.